# scrollview двигается при взаимодействии с внутренним view

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, scrollview

у меня есть scrollview в котором находятся другие view,и с одним из этих view можно взаимодействовать(прокручивать влево-вправо)(view самописный и взаимодействие осуществляется с помощью ontouchEvent), но если я при прокрутке влево или вправо немного сдвину палец вверх или вниз, то фокус на view сбивается и начинает прокручиваться scrollview, как это можно изменить? Ведь если в scrollview будет находится такой же scrollview только другой ориентации, то проблем не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после нескольких дней гуглинга я все же нашел решение:
нужно вызвать метод requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); в OnTouchEvent нашего View для родительского View. этот метод запрещает перехватывать всем родительским View метод OnTouchEvent, что делал scrollView.

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    //ваши действия
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   //ваши действия
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   //ваши действия
                    break;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });
```